# Constructing a specific regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to make a regular expression in Java, with the next criteria:

- Length: 10 characters exactly. Not more, not less.
- Can accept any character between A-Z (only uppercase letters) and between digits 0-9.
- Can accept only one dash character '-' in any position. It cannot accept any other characters, strictly only one dash.

EXAMPLES:

- ABCD-12345
- F-01234GHK
- 09-PL89GG5
- LJ8U9N3-Y2
- PLN86D4V-1

I have been making tries with regex of my own invention, some regular expressions that are close to the result I want, but with no success.

Do I have to combine two regular expressions?

Please, help me to get rid of this issue.... and thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you came up with?

Comment: Why don't you check the length using java methods ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need lookahead (which is a way of combining two regular expressions, sort of).

```
^(?!.*-.*-)[A-Z0-9-]{10}$
```

The second part will match 10 characters that are A-Z, 0-9, or dash; the first part is *negative lookahead* that will reject a pattern that has two dashes in it.

Comment: This works fine for what I needed to implement!!! Also using `matches` method which is what I am using actually!!!

Thanks for the solution!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
^(?![^-]*+-[^-]*+-)[A-Z0-9-]{10}$
```

Note: If you use the `matches` method you can remove anchors.

Comment: Can you add a demo link it seems not to work on the example given

Comment: @amir What input doesn't this work on?  I've tried it with [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) and it seems OK.

Comment: But it works for the above answer if you remove the `^` `$`. Anw your answer could be right as well

Comment: @Amir: Because you are testing a string that is longer than 10 characters since you have pasted all the example strings

Comment: Shouldn't it work for all the lines separately ? That's what I tried for the second answer

Comment: @Amir: If you want to make it work as it with regex101, add the m modifier. But the question is clear: **Length: 10 characters exactly. Not more, not less**. If you remove the anchors, the pattern can accept any string length greater than or equal to 10.

Comment: I am acutally using `matches` method. What else can I do?

Comment: @Ayuchuco: only to understand what a pattern means.